# Getting correct selections outside of a change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, input

I am running into an issue that I absolutely cannot figure out. I initially check to see which checkboxes are selected. (Run the console to see that the values are correct). Then based on the selection a new div will appear for the appropriate initial selection. Once you click on the nested checkbox the console will show the Price - "Initial Selection".

The code within my snippet works exactly as it should, but for some reason in my actual code it will not recognize the correct packages within the second event handler `$('.check').on('change', function() {`.

For instance, if Package 1 and 2 are the initial selections, the appropriate div will appear, like in this case `#combined`, but then once the checkbox is selected for "What time is it?", the `console.log()` will show only Package 1.

If package 2 is solely selected, it will show the correct div, but then stop there ... the `console.log()` won't show because it doesn't get to the `if else`.

The only option that works correctly is if Package 1 is selected solely.

So since I was able to get the snippet to work my question is if there is another way to be sure my product change event is recognized throughout different functions and sections...outside of its own change function. Is this needed? I have no other idea why within the second change function, how the correct product selections are not being recognized.

This is what my actual code is producing in the console...

[image]

I have too much code to post the actual, but it is structured the exact same way.

Any ideas for what I can do to get the actual selections outside of the change function?

```js
var package1 = $('#package1');
var package2 = $('#package2');
$('.product').on('change', function() {
  if (package1.is(':checked') && package2.is(':checked')) {
    console.log("Initial - Package 1 & 2");
    $('#combined').show();
    $('#pack1-details').hide();
    $('#pack2-details').hide();
  } else if (package2.not(':checked') && package1.is(':checked')) {
    console.log("Initial - Package 1");
    $('#combined').hide();
    $('#pack2-details').hide();
    $('#pack1-details').show();
  } else if (package1.not(':checked') && package2.is(':checked')) {
    console.log("Initial - Package 2");
    $('#pack2-details').show();
  }
});
$('.check').on('change', function() {
  if (package1.is(':checked') && package2.is(':checked')) {
    console.log("Price - Package 1 & 2");

  } else {
    if (package1.is(':checked')) {
      console.log("Price - Package 1");
    } else if (package2.is(':checked')) {
      console.log("Price - Package 2");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#combined,
#pack1-details,
#pack2-details {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Package 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="product" id="package1">
<label>Package 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="product" id="package2">
<div id="combined">
  <p>Package 1 & 2</p>
  <div class="check">
    <label>What time is it?</label>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="pack1-details">
  <p>Package 1 only</p>
  <div class="check">
    <label>When does Spring start?</label>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="pack2-details">
  <p>Package 2 only</p>
  <div class="check">
    <label>Where is Greece?</label>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There must be a difference between your snippet and actual code. Are package1 and package2 actually global in your real code? Are they in scope? You can always move the var package1 = $('#package1'); inside the  on change handler to be sure. Also you don't happen to have multiple (non-unique) ids on the page? More elements named package1 or so?

Comment: @Martina Here is my javascript. `package1` and 2 are global. So I am not sure. The second change function from my example in this question is at the end of the js http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBxNRO?editors=0010

Comment: The id of package1 and package2 are only once within the html.

Comment: The variables are not global they are inside onready, you have to move them out, above, I'll make it an answer below as I can't post code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables are not in scope (global) in your actual code, they are local to .ready.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        // ******** General
        $('#package-section1').show();
        var package1 = $('#package1');
        var package2 = $('#package2');
```

change it to:

```
var package1;
var package2;

 jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            // ******** General
            $('#package-section1').show();
            package1 = $('#package1');
            package2 = $('#package2');
```

To access current state of each checkbox you need to select it at the time of click or change event, the global variables are a snapshot of the checkboxes at the time when they were assigned.
So you need to do something like this:

```
 $('.calendar-check').on('change', function () {
       var package1 = $('#package1');
       var package2 = $('#package2');
        //    $('input.example').not(this).prop('checked', false);
       // if (!this.checked || $('.calendar-check:checked').length <= limitCal) {
         if ($('input.calendar-check').not(this).attr('checked', false)) {
            $(this).parents('.product-wrap:first').find('.checkmark-img').fadeBoolToggle(this.checked);
            if (package2.prop('checked', false)) {
                $('#pg-preview-wrap').fadeBoolToggle($('.calendar-check:checked').length > 0);
                if ($('.calendar-check:checked').length > 0) {
                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#pg-preview-wrap').offset().top }, 800);
                }
                else if ($('.calendar-check:checked').length == 0) {
                    $('#next2').hide();
                }
            }
```

...

Comment: Thank you, but it seems those changes did not help, unless I did something wrong? Here is a code pen which has my full code in it. If you open the console and select package 1 & 2 and then click on either 2-year calendar, whiteboard or at a glance. You will see the `Price - Package 1` show up in the console, rather than 1 & 2.... so still the issue. Did I not make the variables global in the correct way? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpeoLq

Comment: If you want to check the current state you'll have to select inside the onclick, I'll update my answer, no need for global variables actually :)

Comment: Still nothing after that. You can see within the codepen that it doesn't work and my actual code is the same. I do not understand why. Do you see anything else that could be causing it?

Comment: Line 32 is your toggle for the products, I don't see the selection for packages there, you have to do it in every .change or .click function where you want to access the current state.

Comment: Still isn't recognizing Package 1 & 2. .. changes applied to the code pen. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpeoLq

Comment: It is recognising them, package 2 is actually not checked, something is unchecking it. Also 'package2.not(':checked') ' returns an array it's incorrectly used you could use '$('#package2').is(':checked') === false' instead. To be honest I don't have time to debug right now, maybe later.

Comment: Ok, I removed the `.not()` and structured it how you suggested. That did not solve this issue. How and what could be unchecking it? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpeoLq

Comment: One place I can see that sets 'checked' to false is line 82:   if ($('input.calendar-check').not(this).attr('checked', false)) {....   that's not a check for 'checked' attribute, you are passing it false, so it sets it to false. It's in a lot of places actually, there are checks for 'checked' in about 3 different wrong ways, just use the .is(':checked') === true  or false.

Comment: I changed it to `if ($('input.calendar-check').attr('checked', false))` ... the issue is still present. I am not sure if my change was what was needed though. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpeoLq

Comment: that line sets it to false...why would you change it to that?

Comment: That did it. Thank you for all of your help! I thought the `.not()` function could be used for comparison like `is()` can be.